# Show Fourier transform in the distributional sense

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

Using

$$F[\theta] = \pi \delta(\xi) + i p.v. \frac{1}{\xi}$$

and

$$F[\theta(-x)] = \pi \delta(\xi) - i p.v. \frac{1}{\xi}$$

and

$$p.v. \frac{1}{\xi^{2}} = - (p.v. \frac{1}{\xi})'$$

show the Fourier transforms

$$F[p.v. \frac{1}{x^{2}}] = -\pi |\xi|, \quad F[|x|] = -2 p.v. \frac{1}{\xi^{2}}.$$

Where $\theta$ is the Heaviside function and $F[]$ is the Fourier transform.

Edit: Not sure why this was downvoted for showing clarity but I copied the problem statement from the textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first:
$$
\mathcal{F}\{ \frac{1}{x^2} \}
= \mathcal{F}\{ -(\frac{1}{x})' \}
= - \mathcal{F}\{ (\frac{1}{x})' \}
= -i\xi \, \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{1}{x} \}
= -i\xi \, \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{1}{2i}(\mathcal{F}\{\theta(x)\}-\mathcal{F}\{\theta(-x)\}) \} \\
= -\frac{1}{2}\xi \, \mathcal{F}\{ (\mathcal{F}\{\theta(x)\}-\mathcal{F}\{\theta(-x)\}) \}
= -\frac{1}{2}\xi \, (\mathcal{F}\{\mathcal{F}\{\theta(x)\}\} - \mathcal{F}\{\mathcal{F}\{\theta(-x)\}\} ) \\
= -\frac{1}{2}\xi \, (2\pi\,\theta(-\xi) - 2\pi\,\theta(\xi) )
= \pi\xi \, (\theta(\xi) - \theta(-\xi) )
= \pi\xi \operatorname{sign}(\xi)
= \pi |\xi|.
$$

The second:
$$
\mathcal{F}\{|x|\}
= \frac{1}{\pi} \mathcal{F}\{\pi|x|\}
= \frac{1}{\pi} \mathcal{F}\{\mathcal{F}\{\frac{1}{\xi^2}\}\}
= \frac{1}{\pi} \, 2\pi\frac{1}{(-\xi)^2}
= \frac{2}{\xi^2}.
$$
I don't get the minus sign that you give, however. Have I made an error, or have you made an error, or has the teacher made an error?

Comment: The reason is that you're using the convention $\mathcal F[\phi](\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R} \phi(x) e^{-i \xi x} dx$ (for a test function $\phi$), for which $\mathcal F[\theta](\xi) = \pi \delta(\xi) - i/\xi$.

Comment: @md2perpe I checked again. So the problem from the book actually has the minus sign. I will go through the solution you presented and see if you made a mistake or whether the book has.

Comment: Now I saw that you have a minus sign in the first result, too. My error (if any) must be in the first calculation.

Comment: I've now found the source of the sign error. It's in the given formulas for $\mathcal{F}\{\theta(x)\}$ and $\mathcal{F}\{\theta(-x)\}$. Either you or the book has mixed up the two formulas:
$$1 = \mathcal{F}\{\delta\} = \mathcal{F}\{\theta'\} = i\xi\,\mathcal{F}\{\theta\}  \implies \mathcal{F}\{\theta\} =-\text{pv}\frac{1}{\xi} + C \delta(\xi)$$
for some constant $C$. But the formula given above has a plus sign.